# Can $\tan(x)$ be expressed as a sum of $\cos$ and $\sin$?

Tags: trigonometry

It doesn't matter if its only $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$. It can $\cos(x/2)$ and $\sin(x/2)$, or even $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x/2)$.

Comment: $$\tan x = 2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\sin(2nx)$$

Comment: For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ you have that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are bounded functions, while $\tan(x)$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, if you mean a sum (and not a series, i.e., an *infinite* sum).

Any finite sum of $\cos$'s and $\sin$'s will be bounded since $\lvert\cos\rvert \leq 1$ and $\lvert\sin\rvert \leq 1$ (namely, if you sum $k$ of them, then the sum is at most $k$). However, $\tan$ is unbounded:
$$
\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan x = \infty
$$

Comment: I don't think finiteness was specified

Comment: The OP wrote "sum", not "series" or "infinite sum", which I take as implicitly implying finiteness. @RushabhMehta

Comment: Fair enough I guess

Answer (score 1):

No, just look at the graph.  $\tan x$ goes off to infinity, while $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ do not.

This is kind of a flip answer, but can be made precise.  Write $\tan x=a \cos x + b \sin x$.  The right cannot get larger than $|a|+|b|$ but $\tan x$ can.

Comment: I don't know why all the answerers are making the assumption the sum is finite.

Comment: @RushabhMehta: probably because the *infinite sums* are usually called *series* and not *sums*. It is an important distinction since in $\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1}\sin(2nx)$ the *order* of summation *matters*, by the Riemann-Dini theorem.